# How do I execute a method of a class using an array of methods in the class?

Tags: java, arrays, reflection

What I'm trying to do is execute a method in a class without knowing the method name. I have an array of methods from the class, and an index in of what method it is in the array, but not the actual method. This is what I attempted...but I don't know how to actually do it.

```
Class blocks = Blocks.class;
Method[] methods = blocks.getDeclaredMethods();
Blocks block = new Blocks();
String a = block.(methods[blockBox.getSelectedIndex()]);
```

Is there anyway to do it? I also can't rewrite my code to better suit this one situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For instance methods:

```
String a = (String) methods[blockBox.getSelectedIndex()].invoke(block);
```

For static methods:

```
String a = (String) methods[blockBox.getSelectedIndex()].invoke(null);
```

Provided that the methods have return type String and no parameters

Answer (score 0):

Call `invoke()` method on the index you have got [check this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html)